# Python: How to join string elements in list with complex notation

Tags: python, list

***Edited to show more accurate strings***

I have a long list with the following grouping structure. I am showing just two groups, but in reality there are 300. The strings can be any random collection of numbers and letters:

```py
["['P431', 'N7260', 'K492'], ['R109', 'T075X9A'], ['U8154', 'C861']",
 "['R878X8', 'T61'], ['F6332', 'Q7979'], ['L520'], ['B7939', 'K5132']"]
```

For each group in the list, I want the final output to look like the following:

```py
[['P431 N7260 K492 R109 T075X9A', 'U8154 C861'],
['R878X8 T61 F6332 Q7979 L520', 'B7939 K5132']]
```

So for each group in the list, I want to join all of the elements in every sub-list except the last sub-list, then separately join all of the elements in the last sub-list, and finally add these both together into a single sub-list, each of which will now have just two elements. Thank you in advance as I am a beginner.

Comment: Are those double quotes supposed to be there? Because right now, you just have a list of two strings. You'd be much better off with brackets instead.

Comment: Yes that is how the output is currently and what I am working with. But there are 300 strings instead of 2. Maybe list of lists is not the right terminology here, sorry

Comment: How was this long list generated? You should fix the issue upstream

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
from ast import literal_eval

example=[
    "['P431', 'N7260', 'K492'], ['R109', 'T075X9A'], ['U8154', 'C861']",
    "['R878X8', 'T61'], ['F6332', 'Q7979'], ['L520'], ['B7939', 'K5132']",
    "['a','b','c'], 'not a list'"
]

for st in example:
    *first_grp,last=literal_eval(st)
    if any(not isinstance(s, list) for s in (first_grp, last)):
        continue 
    print([" ".join([e for r in first_grp for e in r]), " ".join(last)])
```

Prints:

```
['P431 N7260 K492 R109 T075X9A', 'U8154 C861']
['R878X8 T61 F6332 Q7979 L520', 'B7939 K5132']
```

This is similar to [Andrej Kesely](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77304813/298607) solution but may overcome the 'random strings' you describe with a type check.

Comment: This worked precisely. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you'have some typos in your string (missing `'`). You can try:

```py
from ast import literal_eval

l = [
    "['cat', 'dog', 'mouse'], ['squirrel', 'lion'], ['fox', 'rabbit']",
    "['chipmunk', 'lion'], ['hyena', 'wolf'], ['owl', 'sloth']",
]

l = [
    [" ".join(w for ll in subl for w in ll), " ".join(last)]
    for s in l
    for *subl, last in [literal_eval(s)]
]

print(l)
```

Prints:

```
[
  ['cat dog mouse squirrel lion', 'fox rabbit'], 
  ['chipmunk lion hyena wolf', 'owl sloth']
]
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked to some extent, but for some of the 300 groups in the list, it started to stretch out the sequences so it read like ['c a t d o g m o u s e ...', 'f o x r a b b i t']]

Comment: @JTA1618 You probably have different strings in your list `l` as you've showed in your example (not lists with words, but just plain words)

Comment: @JTA1618 if that's the case, the format/schema of your example data doesn't match your actual data

Comment: Thank you. Yes, sorry, I have different strings. They have the format X139, J000A, XT189X, etc - every word item is made of random character(s) and numbers. Your code works for some items but not for others. Is there a way I could amend the code to work for any item containing random characters and numbers?

Comment: @JTA1618 Please edit your question and put there your real example and expected output.

Comment: @JTA1618 With your new list you've posted in your question I get expected output. But you can try Dawg's answer.

Answer (score 2):

use ast.literal_eval for construct list from string, then join with space all except the last and then union all together

```
import ast
result = []

for group in data:
    subgroups = ast.literal_eval(group)

    # join all except last
    combined = [' '.join(subgroup) for subgroup in subgroups[:-1]]
    # last append   
    last_subgroup = ' '.join(subgroups[-1])

    
    result.append([' '.join(combined), last_subgroup])

print(result)
```

Comment: Thank you. Both of the answers above worked to some extent, but for some of the 300 groups in the list, it started to stretch out the sequences so it read like  ['c a t d o g m o u s e ...', 'f o x r a b b i t']]

Comment: With [ast](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) there is absolutely no reason to use `eval`.

Comment: @dawg thank you for correction with ast agree - fixed

Comment: @JTA1618 Could you please share example which doesn't work?